# How to detect screen orientation size or view port on Using Bootstrap5?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, bootstrap-5

As I am new to bootstrap, Just now I developed the videoCall layout, which is responsive, but I've checked the inspect tools using dimensions in some device viewport orientations that are not responsive.

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  }
  /* main video */
  .main-video video{
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    position: absolute;
    object-fit: contain;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  
  #main-video{
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }
  
  
  .videoWrap{
    position: relative;
  max-width: 320px;
  display: inline-block;
  }
  .videoWrap #logo{
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2rem;
  right: 1rem;
  }
  .videoWrap #logo img{
  width: 40px;
  }
  
  .video-list video{
  
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  max-width: 320px;
  margin: 0 1rem 1rem 0;
  border-radius: 1.25rem;
  z-index: 2;
  }
  .user-name{
  color: #fff;
  float: left;
  padding: 0.125rem 0.25rem;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  margin: 0.5rem 0 0 1rem;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width:768px){
  .videoWrap,
  .video-list video{
      max-width: 217px;
  }
  }
  
  
  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 200px) and (max-device-width: 992px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    .videoWrap,
    .video-list video{
        max-width: 150px;
    }
   .videoWrap, #dropDown {
      margin: -0.8rem 0.2rem -1.8rem -0.3rem;
      left: 31px;
      bottom: 4px;
    }
    .videoWrap .user-name{
      margin: -0.8rem 0.2rem -1.8rem -0.3rem;
      left: 31px;
      bottom: 4px;
    }
  }
  
  @media screen and (max-width:480px){
  .videoWrap,
  .video-list video{
      max-width: 149px;
      bottom: 4rem;
  }
  .videoWrap #logo{
    bottom: 1.5rem;
  }
  .videoWrap #logo img{
    width: 30px;
  }
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <body>
 
<div  class="container-fluid m-0" id="videos m-0">

      <div class="row vh-100 align-items-end align-items-lg-center m-0" >
  <div class="col-12 offset-lg-10 col-lg-2 text-center text-lg-end ">
        <div  id="Media">

      <div  class=" main-video mainVideoWrap" id="cardvideo_localstream">
         <video id="video-main" class="video1" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/ve0apo59semvv70/example-video-1.mp4?raw=1 " muted autoplay loop type="video/mp4" ></video>
        <div class="card-img-overlay p-0  " id="mainCard">
          <div>
            <span class="text-capitalize user-name">
              <i class="icon-user pe-1"></i>videoBg
            </span>
            <div id="dropDown" class="dropdown float-end">
              <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger me-3 mt-2 dropdown-toggle" type="button"  id="userMenu"   data-bs-toggle="dropdown"   aria-expanded="false">
                <i class="icon-dot"></i>
              </button>
              <ul id="drop"  class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end"   aria-labelledby="userMenu"  >
                <li>
                  <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#"  >
                    <i class="bi bi-mic-mute m-1"></i>Start Audio</a >
                  </li>
                <li>
                  <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#"  ><i class="bi bi-camera-video-off m-1"></i>Stop Video</a >
                </li>
                <li>
                  <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#" ><i class="bi bi-person-x m-1"></i>Remove</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
   
      <!-- <div class="row vh-100 align-items-end align-items-lg-center m-0"> -->
        <div class=" video-list listofvideos">
          <div class="position-relative videoWrap" id="cardvideo_remotestream">
            <video  src=" https://www.dropbox.com/s/se8r4svvnt2qpfu/example-video-2.mp4?raw=1 " muted  autoplay loop type="video/mp4" ></video>
            <div class="card-img-overlay p-0  " id="imgCard">
              <div>
                <span class="text-capitalize user-name">
                  <i class="icon-user pe-1"></i>videolist1
                </span>
                <div id="dropDown" class="dropdown float-end">
                  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger me-3 mt-2 dropdown-toggle"  type="button"  id="userMenu"  data-bs-toggle="dropdown"   aria-expanded="false">
                    <i class="icon-dot"></i>
                  </button>
                  <ul id="drop" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="userMenu" >
                    <li>
                      <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#"  ><i class="bi bi-mic-mute m-1"></i>Start Audio</a  >
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#"   ><i class="bi bi-camera-video-off m-1"></i>Stop Video</a >
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#"  ><i class="bi bi-person-x m-1"></i>Remove</a  >
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
          
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="position-relative videoWrap" id="cardvideo_remotestream">
            <video   src=" https://www.dropbox.com/s/se8r4svvnt2qpfu/example-video-2.mp4?raw=1 "  muted  ></video>
            <div class="card-img-overlay p-0  " id="imgCard">
              <div>
                <span class="text-capitalize user-name">
                  <i class="icon-user pe-1"></i>videolist2
                </span>
                <div id="dropDown" class="dropdown float-end">
                  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger me-3 mt-2 dropdown-toggle"  type="button"   id="userMenu"  data-bs-toggle="dropdown"   aria-expanded="false" >
                    <i class="icon-dot"></i>
                  </button>
                  <ul  id="drop"   class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="userMenu" >
                    <li>
                 <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#"  ><i class="bi bi-mic-mute m-1"></i>Start Audio</a  >
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#"  ><i class="bi bi-camera-video-off m-1"></i>Stop Video</a >
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#"   ><i class="bi bi-person-x m-1"></i>Remove</a >
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
           
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="position-relative videoWrap" id="cardvideo_remotestream">
            <video  src=" https://www.dropbox.com/s/se8r4svvnt2qpfu/example-video-2.mp4?raw=1 "  muted  autoplay loop type="video/mp4"></video>
            <div class="card-img-overlay p-0  " id="imgCard">
              <div>
                <span class="text-capitalize user-name">
                  <i class="icon-user pe-1"></i>videolist3
                </span>
                <div id="dropDown" class="dropdown float-end">
                  <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger me-3 mt-2 dropdown-toggle" type="button"  id="userMenu" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false" >
                    <i class="icon-dot"></i>
                  </button>
                  <ul id="drop" class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end" aria-labelledby="userMenu">
                    <li>
                      <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#" ><i class="bi bi-mic-mute m-1"></i>Start Audio</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="bi bi-camera-video-off m-1"></i>Stop Video</a >
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#" ><i class="bi bi-person-x m-1"></i>Remove</a>
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
           
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="position-relative videoWrap" id="cardvideo_remotestream">
            <video  src=" https://www.dropbox.com/s/se8r4svvnt2qpfu/example-video-2.mp4?raw=1 " muted  autoplay loop type="video/mp4"></video>
            <div class="card-img-overlay p-0 " id="imgCard">
              <div>
                <span class="text-capitalize user-name">
                  <i class="icon-user pe-1"></i>videolist4
                </span>
                <div id="dropDown" class="dropdown float-end">
                  <button  class="btn btn-sm btn-danger me-3 mt-2 dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="userMenu" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"
                  >
                    <i class="icon-dot"></i>
                  </button>
                  <ul  id="drop"  class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end"  aria-labelledby="userMenu" >
                    <li>
                      <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#" ><i class="bi bi-mic-mute m-1"></i>Start Audio</a >
                    </li>
                    <li>  <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#"
                        ><i class="bi bi-camera-video-off m-1"></i>Stop Video</a  >
                    </li>
                    <li>
                      <a id="dropdown_items" class="dropdown-item" href="#"
                        ><i class="bi bi-person-x m-1"></i>Remove</a  >
                    </li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
        
            </div>
          </div>
        <!-- </div> -->
      </div>

      <!-- row column -->
    </div>
    </div>
    
  </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  <script src="./bootstrap/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


</html>
```

I need to,

while in landscape orientation the list of videos`(class name -> videolists)` align vertically in right side corner, while in portrait orientation the list of videos will be aligned horizontally bottom,

How to detect screen orientation size  Bootstrap5?

Comment: Out of width, height, and orientation, only width is available (and only in the provided, relative sizes, `-xs`, `-lg`, etc.) via bootstrap. If you want height or orientation dependencies, you'll need to develop those yourself or use a different framework.